# Google OAuth - birhtday and location

Tags: oauth, scope

I'm using Google's OAUTH2 for authorization. This is the data I get after successfully authorization.

```
[id] => 113430878981958293839 
[email] => adrian.1358@gmail.com 
[verified_email] => 1 
[name] => Adrian S. 
[given_name] => Adrian 
[family_name] => S. 
[link] => https://plus.google.com/113430878981958293839 
[picture] => https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-HjS4maAginM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAFc/uDKmwu49Y-Y/photo.jpg 
[gender] => male 
[locale] => hr
```

Im using scopes: openid,profile and email.

Is it possible to get user's location and birthday?!

Tnx alot!

Answer (score 0):

If the birthday is available (i.e. the user put it into their profile), then you will see it in the response to your call. As for location, I'm not sure that any of Google's API will show you the user's location.